# how to get executed command name in beforeCommand or AfterCommand event - WYSIHTML5?

Tags: jquery, wysihtml5, bootstrap-wysihtml5

Is there exist a way to figure out which command is fired in "beforecommand:Composer" event ?
i.e :

```
Editor.on("beforecommand:composer", function () {
    console.log(commandName);
});
```

I used editor in chat application so I need to catch event name and values to save formatting after clear the textarea.